# Modelsim is not working after ubuntu 11.10 upgrade?

Tags: 11.10

I have the error when I tried to run the modelsim 6.6d and display this below and it was fine in previously 11.04 version

> Error: cannot find
>   /home/mark/altera/11.0/modelsim_ase/bin/../linux_rh60/vlog The vlog
>   should be in directory of /home/mark/altera/11.0/modelsim_ase/bin/vlog

But, I don't understand why is looking for `linux_rh60/vlog`?

Has anyone seen this error before?

Answer (score 5):

To  fix this, you have to edit the vsim file with

```
gksu gedit vsim
```

in the bin directory. The thing is that if the linux version is 3.x.x.x there a condition that searches in an unexistent directory, so edit the line (204 aprox.)

```
  *)                vco="linux_rh60" ;;
```

to:

```
***)                vco="linux" ;;**
```

also, you have to change the line 13 (first non-comment line)

```
  mode=${MTI_VCO_MODE:-""}
```

to

```
  **mode=${MTI_VCO_MODE:-"32"}**
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 I only had to change "linux_rh60" to "linux"